# Awk not outputting in scientific notation despite %e

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk for some basic calculations and want to force my output to be in scientific notation. I am using `OFMT="%.15e"` to accomplish this. On most machines, I get the expected output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%.15e"; print 4.483923595133619e+29 / 1000 }'
4.483923595133619e+26
```

But a version of awk on my cluster gives:

```
$ awk --version | head --lines=2
GNU Awk 4.0.2
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.

$ awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%.15e"; print 4.483923595133619e+29 / 1000 }'
448392359513361882871234560
```

Why is this version/configuration of awk not outputting to scientific notation as requested? How can I portably get my desired result (`4.483923595133619e+26` )?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you could ask at comp.lang.awk on usenet where all the awk experts and gawk providers hang out or contact help<dash>gawk<at>gnu<dot>org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I believe you've found a longstanding bug in GNU awk.</strike>

GNU awk is behaving correctly.

Here's [what POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

> A numeric value that is exactly equal to the value of an integer (see Concepts Derived from the ISO C Standard) shall be converted to a string by the equivalent of a call to the `sprintf` function (see String Functions) with the string `"%d"` as the `fmt` argument and the numeric value being converted as the first and only `expr` argument.

Using `printf` rather than setting `OFMT` is not a workaround for a gawk bug. It's the solution to the bug in your code.

Any sufficiently large floating-point value is exactly equal to an integer.

(The way awk distinguishes between integers and non-integers by their values can be a bit confusing if you're accustomed to languages that have distinct integer and floating-point types.)

Here's a demonstration of what's happening:

```
$ cat foo.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFMT="%.16e"
    for (i = 50; i <= 55; i ++) {
        x = 2 ** i - 0.5
        printf("2**%d - 0.5 = %.3f = ", i, x)
        print(x)
    }
}
$ ./foo.awk
2**50 - 0.5 = 1125899906842623.500 = 1.1258999068426235e+15
2**51 - 0.5 = 2251799813685247.500 = 2.2517998136852475e+15
2**52 - 0.5 = 4503599627370495.500 = 4.5035996273704955e+15
2**53 - 0.5 = 9007199254740992.000 = 9007199254740992
2**54 - 0.5 = 18014398509481984.000 = 18014398509481984
2**55 - 0.5 = 36028797018963968.000 = 36028797018963968
$
```

I initially thought this was a bug in gawk, and I submitted a bug report here:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-05/msg00010.html

A reply from Andrew J. Schorr correctly says that this is the expected behavior.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-05/msg00011.html

There have been more responses on the mailing list. The documentation is probably insufficiently clear about the relationship between `OFMT` and `CONVFMT`. The POSIX wording I cited above is talking about `CONVFMT`.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-05/threads.html

Answer (score 1):

I did run

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%.15e"; print 4.483923595133619e+29 / 1000 }'
```

using **gawk 4.2.1** and it did give

```
448392359513361882871234560
```

I was unable to find reason for that, but determined that using [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) does what you want, that is

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf("%.15e\n", 4.483923595133619e+29 / 1000) }'
```

using **gawk 4.2.1** did give

```
4.483923595133619e+26
```

Observe need to apply line terminator yourself (`\n` means newline). Please try it with your `awk` and write if it does work as intended.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I am still waiting to learn why this issue occurs in the first place, however.

Comment: Turns out it's not a bug. See my answer.